# IBM MQ acknowledgements are happening whenever session consumes all messages

Tags: ibm-mq

I am facing the weird issue that consumer fetches all available messages from IBM MQ but then when I acknowledge even few messages, all messages which are consumed are already dequeued.

```
Message msg = consumer.receive(POLL_TIMEOUT_INTERVAL);
messageBuffer.put(msg);
```

Not all messages from message buffer are acknowledged explicitly but looks like all of them are dequeued from Queue

Comment: commit is at the session level not at the message level.  If you commit it will do it for all outstanding uncommitted messages for the session.

Comment: Thanks Josh but is there any way I can acknowledge  at the message level

Comment: Different sessions